# Vagrant Windows-1251 encoding error

Tags: vagrant

I got the next error with vagrant when trying to use "vagrant up" command:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'precise32'...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/childprocess-0.5.3/lib/childprocess/wind
ows/process_builder.rb:43:in `join': incompatible character encodings: Windows-1
251 and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
```

I have Windows 8.1, and I used "chcp 1251" command before, because it was the same error with "ibm866" encoding.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, problem was solved by setting environment variable VAGRANT_HOME

Comment: could you provide that as an answer and "accept" it? that will help others who may search and find the same issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem was solved by setting environment variable VAGRANT_HOME

Answer (score 8):

the solution for me was this one .

You have to go to : `c:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.6.3\bin\vagrant`

And edit the vagrant (file) and put after this : `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`

this 2 lines

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding.find('Windows-1250')
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding.find('Windows-1250')
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

1. Set an environtment variable `VAGRANT_HOME` to the path, for example '`c:\HashiCorp`'
2. Then add to `c:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.6.3\bin\vagrant` after  `#!/usr/bin/env` ruby these two lines:

`Encoding.default_external = Encoding.find('Windows-1251')`

`Encoding.default_internal = Encoding.find('Windows-1251')`

Notice `Windows-1251`, not `Windows-1250`.

And I think you might need to reboot to enable the environment variable.

Comment: Had the same issue today, solved by setting `VARGANT_HOME` variable AND both `Encoding` to `windows-1251`. Some useful infornation could also be found here https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12121

Answer (score 0):

Yes, setting environment variable `VAGRANT_HOME` can solve the problem.

I think it's mainly because `vagrant up` command would try to visit `%userprofile%\.vagrant.d` folder, however, your `%userprofile%` is named in `Windows 1251` encoding. Setting `VAGRANT_HOME` can point to a path recognizable for vagrant's ruby script.

Answer (score 0):

If you stil having some trouble with it, even after seting env variable, try just to move your "homestead" folder to a path that not contains any cyrilic symbols.
Or you can create another user in you system without cyrilc
Hope it helps!